# Как сделать так чтобы работали две функции от одной кнопки tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно сделать так что бы от одна кнопка enter выполняла две функции: 1)Если пользователь не ввёл какие-либо данные то запускала текст(это я сделал) 2)Если всё правильно, то нужно что бы всё окно очищалось и выводились другие слова(Вот в это я и не могу грамотно сделать). Потому что всегда приходится нажимать на кнопку два раза

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
user_dict = {}
root = Tk()
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.password = None

def check(event):# Проверка наличия всех данных
    n = login.get()
    p = password.get()
    if n and p:
        text_lol.pack()
        text_lol.place(x = 100, y = 195)
        enter.bind('<Button - 1>',next_1,next_2)
    if not n and p:
        text_not_ok_login.pack()
        text_not_ok_login.place(x = 20, y = 100)
    elif not p and n:
        text_not_ok_password.pack()
        text_not_ok_password.place(x = 20, y = 165)

def next_1(event):
    destroy_object = [text_parc,text_login,text_password,text_not_ok_login,login,password,enter,text_not_ok_password,enter,text_lol]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()

def next_2(event):
    text_login2.pack()
    text_login2.place(x = 20, y = 50)


root.geometry('300x450')
root.title('Войти в cиcтему')
root['bg'] = 'white'
text_lol = Label(text = ' - Нажми ещё раз', font = 'Consalas 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')

text_parc = Label(text = 'Вход в парсер', font = 'Consalas 25', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')

text_login = Label(text = 'Логин', font = 'Consalas 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')
login = Entry(root, font = 'Consalas 15', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')
text_login2 = Label(text = 'Логин', font = 'Consalas 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')

text_password = Label(text = 'Пароль', font = 'Comfortaa 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'white')
password = Entry(root, font = 'Consalas 15', fg = 'black', bg = 'white',show = '*')

enter = Button(text='Войти ', font = 'Consalas 15', fg = 'white', bg = '#0000FF')
enter.bind('<Button - 1>',check)

text_not_ok_login = Label(text = 'Вы не ввели логин', font = 'Consalas 7', fg = 'red', bg = 'white')
text_not_ok_password = Label(text = 'Вы не ввели пароль', font = 'Consalas 7', fg = 'red', bg = 'white')

text_parc.pack()
text_login.pack()
text_parc.place(x = 20, y = 5)
text_login.place(x = 20, y = 50)
login.pack()
login.place(x = 20, y = 70)
text_password.pack()
password.pack()
text_password.place(x = 20, y = 115)
password.place(x = 20, y = 135)
enter.pack()
enter.place(x = 20, y = 190)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну, смотрите, если вам надо сделать 2 функции для одной кнопки, то надо одну привязать как параметр `command` в самой кнопке, а вторую просто забиндить.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно просто в ветке `if n and p` вызвать нужные функции

```
if n and p:
    next_1()
    next_2()
```

И в функции `next_1()` и в `next_2` убрать аргумент event, тк он здесь не нужен